# Sorting 2 lists, restricted commands, malloc and pointers

Tags: c, list, sorting, unix, malloc

Basically I have to create a program in which `la` is given a parameter, and then I have some specific commands that have to be used to sort them numbers in la into another array, `lb`.

I suppose my prototype should be something like:

```
int functioname(la) {
    //something here
}
```

My question is how to use malloc to create the `lb` big enough to fit all the numbers in `la`, I have tried to use something like:

```
lb = malloc(sizeof(la));
```

but it doesn't seem to work out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using malloc , you have to carefull it returns a void pointer , so you should type cast it.If your parameter is a pointer to the array , you need to find out the lenght of the array. The function prototype has to be int* not int because it has to send back the pointer to the dinamically alocated memory. My piece of code would be `int *a =(int*)malloc(numer-of-elememts*sizeof(int));`

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out:

```
int pushswap(int *la) {
 int *lb;
 int cnt;

 cnt = 0;
 while(la[cnt])
   cnt++;
  lb = malloc(sizeof(int)*cnt + 1)
}
```